# How to declare multiple pointer-to-pointer using while in C?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, while-loop

I have this code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_ultimate_ft(int *********nbr)
{
    printf("%d", *********nbr);
}

int main(){
    /*Start of problem*/
    int *a;
    int **b = &a;
    int ***c = &b;
    int ****d = &c;
    int *****e = &d;
    int ******f = &e;
    int *******g = &f;
    int ********h = &g;
    int *********i = &h;
    /*end of problem*/
    *********i = 42;
    ft_ultimate_ft(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to include pointer-to-pointer declaration in the loop (for example, while). It's needed to decrease number of declarations.

Comment: What is this? Who gave this requirement?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Anyway, you can loop over values, not types.

Comment: You're not at all concerned that `a` is indeterminate, and as such the wheels completely fell off the wagon you're already riding in?

Comment: See this: http://wiki.c2.com/?FiveStarProgrammer

Comment: Read about how compiler works, how memory allocated to variables (at run time and compile time)?

Comment: You can't do this in a loop. The number of asterisks is part of the type, a concept that exists only during compile time.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you __actually__ trying to do?

Comment: This cannot be done in a loop, if you do not declare each intermediate pointer you loose a link in the chain and you cannot recover the variable. Also note that you are missing an `int` before the variable `a`. Here you have only pointers and no real "container" for you variable

Comment: None of this make any sense. In particularly "It's needed to decrease number of declarations" is nonsense.

Comment: If you want to a) absolutely do what you asked about b) really want to get into programming and debugging hell, then I recommend to use an array of pointers to void and use them with generous type casting back and forth. I also recommend: Don't.

Comment: @interjay It was a programming school task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that I have properly understood you question, which is to create a multiple pointer to a number using a loop and then assign value to it.

I wrote a piece of code that partly completes your requirement but still need to know how many layers there are after the loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
void ft_ultimate_ft(int *********nbr)
{
    printf("%d", *********nbr);
}

int main() {
    int t = 10;
    int n = 8;
    void * p = &t;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        void* * s = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void*));
        *s = p;
        p = s;
    }
    /*end of problem*/
    int *********real = (int *********)p;
    *********real = 42;
    ft_ultimate_ft(real);
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs 42

The clean up part of the program is not written

PS. In your code, the pointer a is indeterminate and I do not think that your original code can work properly.